# Proof that $\varepsilon$-arguments are valid

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

A lot of times when proving for example inequalities like $$x \leq y$$
for real numbers $x,y$ the argument looks like
$$x \leq y + \varepsilon$$
for all $\varepsilon > 0$, hence $x \leq y$.

Now this is obviously very intuitive, but is there a "proof" that this conclusion is correct? And is it always sufficient in order to proof $x \leq y$ to show $x \leq y + \epsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$?

I'd  appreciate any explanations!

**NOTE:** I know that these kinds of arguments are correct when dealing with sequences. But here we have no sequences so I wanted to understand this too.

Comment: To conclude $x \le y$, it suffices to know $x < y + \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @mlc true, but I would like a proof for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Comment: @user1110341  I don't think it does: that post was about intuition, not formal proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. Prove that if $x\le y + \epsilon$ for every positive real number $\epsilon$, then $x \leq y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964310/let-x-and-y-be-real-numbers-prove-that-if-x-le-y-epsilon-for-every-pos) (found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x%5Cle%20y%2B%5Cepsilon%24&p=1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

$$t\le\epsilon$$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Clearly,

$$t\le0$$ is compatible, while

$$t>0$$ is not because

$$0<t\le\epsilon$$ cannot hold for all $\epsilon>0$.

Rewrite with $t:=x-y$.

Comment: That made it clear! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $x < y + \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon >0$, but that $x>y$. Then, taking $\varepsilon = x-y >0$, you obtain $x<x$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x \leqslant y + \varepsilon$ for every positive $\varepsilon$, and for the sake of contradiction, suppose $x > y$.

For the specific error $\varepsilon := \frac{1}{2}(x - y) > 0$ we have that $$x  \leqslant y + \varepsilon < y + 2\varepsilon = y + (x - y) = x,$$ which is a desired contradiction.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. However, is there also a direct proof for this? Just for more clarification that $(\forall \varepsilon > 0: x < y + \varepsilon) \implies (x \leq y)$.

Comment: I meant a proof that does not use contradiction, i.e. $A \implies B$ rather than $\neg B \implies \neg A$

Answer (score 1):

A silly direct proof (for those who don't) like proofs by contradiction).

$x\le y +\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Let $\tau =y-x $.

$y= x +\tau $ so $\tau \le 0$.

So $y \le x $

$-\tau \ge 0$.  So as $x\ge y $ we have $x+(-\tau) \ge y+(-\tau) =y-y+x = x $.  So $-\tau \le 0$.

Well, I guess technically that is a proof by contradict.  Still... I thought it was cute.

So $\tau = y-x=0$.  And $x=y $.