# Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and assume that for all $\epsilon > 0, |x| < \epsilon$. Prove: $x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification

> This following exercise has me kind of confused, it asks: let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and assume that for all $\epsilon > 0, |x| < \epsilon$.
>
> Prove that $x = 0$.

My attempt to this was to use proof by contradiction:

**Proof:** Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and assume that $x > 0.$ Then our $\epsilon=\dfrac{|x|}{2}>0.$ By assumption we have that $0\le x<\epsilon =\dfrac{ |x|}{2},$ so then $x=0$, which contradicts our $x > 0$ claim.

Will this suffice?

Comment: Well, you still need to eliminate the $x<0$ case.  And it isn;t true that $0≤x<\frac {|x|}2\implies x=0$.  Those inequalities are impossible.

Comment: To deal with $x<0$, start instead with assuming $|x|>0$ to get the contradiction that you have.  Since the contradiction says $|x|>0$ is not true, $x$ must be equal to zero.

Comment: Ah damn, wolfram error. Alright let me try it that way for $x<0.$

Comment: If $x > 0$ then setting $e=x $ gives us $|x|=x <x=e$. Which is a contradiction.   But we can do one better.  If $x\ne 0$ then $|x|>0$.  Let $e =|x|$ and we have $|x|<|x|=e $.  Which is a contradiction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition: If $a\leq b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon&gt;0$ then $a\leq b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679038/intuition-if-a-leq-b-epsilon-for-all-epsilon0-then-a-leq-b)

Comment: @user1110341 Same comment as [2 hours ago on that other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210893/proof-that-varepsilon-arguments-are-valid#comment9988937_2210893):  I don't think it does: that post was about intuition, not formal proof. (And though related, the question is distinct.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition about : $a = b \iff | a − b| &lt; \epsilon$, for every $\epsilon &gt; 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436553/intuition-about-a-b-iff-a-%e2%88%92-b-epsilon-for-every-epsilon-0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't suffice because you have not examined small negative numbers.

I would prove it by contradiction.  Assume $x \ne 0$.  Then $|x| >0$  Let $\epsilon = |x|/2$.  Then $|x| > \epsilon$, which contradicts the assumption that $|x| < \epsilon$ for every possible $\epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

All of the previous answers invoke contradiction, but I don't believe there's any need to. One could argue like this: By assumption, $|x|$ is smaller than every positive real number, so in particular it is *different* from every positive real number, so it is not positive. But, by definition, $|x|$ is non-negative. Hence, $|x|$ is zero, so $x$ itself is zero.

Answer (score 0):

It's way simpler than that.

$|x|\ge 0$

If $|x|>0$ then setting $\epsilon=|x|$ we get the contradictory $\epsilon =|x| >|x|$.

So $|x|=0$.  So $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same proof than E.Fisher, just to use the archimedian property.

$(\mathbb R,+,\le)$ is archimedian, so for $0<|x|<\epsilon$ there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n|x|>\epsilon$.

This contradicts $|x|<\varepsilon$ for $\displaystyle \varepsilon=\frac{\epsilon}n$, thus $|x|=0\quad$ (and $x=0$ consequently)